# Using callbacks except in certain cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I have a Rails callback for a quantitative model that updates some numbers based on recent activity, something like:

```
class Data < ActiveRecord::Base
before_validation :check_numbers

def check_numbers
  Check #1...
  Check #2...
  Check #3...
  Check #4...
  ...etc.
end
```

All of these checks add up to quite some time, often a significant fraction of a second.

If I have a controller action that only has any impact on Check #4 - how can I **avoid checking** #1-3? Can I, for example, pass in a variable like [4] that tells this callback to take a shortcut?

Bonus points: is there a way to conveniently do some of this processing on the server-side **after** showing the candidate the next rendered page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing tasks in the background that take some time on the server side can be achieved with delayed job (https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job).

As for only doing a particular check. Maybe something like the following

```
class Data < ActiveRecord::Base
before_validation :check_numbers

def check_numbers
  check_one if to_check.includes? 1
  check_two if to_check.includes? 2
  check_three if to_check.includes? 3
  check_four if to_check.includes? 4
  ...etc.
end

def to_check=(arr_or_checks)
  @to_check = arr_or_checks
end

def to_check
  @to_check
end
```

Then in your controller you could specify what needs to be checked by calling `to_check([1, 3, 9])` for example.

This will add more processing to your code and will also make the Controller aware of logic that it probably should not. To get around this information leak you should make the to_check methods private and set them in methods that are used by the controllers, e.g. `obj.do_x` and `obj.do_y` may set different numbers in the `to_check` array.

===== UPDATE ======

Example

```
test = Data.find(33)
test.to_check = [1,4]
test.update_attributes(params[:test])
```

or
    test = Data.find(33)
    test.to_check = [1,4]
    test.name = "new name"
    test.save

Like I said I am not a huge fan of doing this explicitly in the controller. So I would try to encapsulate this in the model itself as follows.

```
class Data
  ...

  def update_attributes_by_admin(attributes)
    to_check = [1,4]
    update_attributes(attributes)
  end

  def update_attributes_by_reg_user(attributes)
    to_check = [1,2,3,4,...] # use all numbers here.
    update_attributes(attributes)
  end
```

Then back in the controller we could do something like this

```
def admin_action
  ...
  test = Data.find(33)
  test.update_attributes_by_admin(params[:test])
  ...
end

def reg_user_action
  ...
  test = Data.find(33)
  test.update_attributes_by_reg_user(params[:test])
  ...
end
```

Of course it would be safer to actually do the inverse of what I have done in this example. i.e.

```
check_one unless not_to_check.includes? 1
```

and then have `not_to_check` methods instead of the `to_check` etc.

This way all default save/update methods will do the validations and you create the ones that do not do full validations.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear. A few things: 1) why two `to_check` methods in the model? 2) How would I specify what needs to be checked upon saving/validating? Can I do, for example: @data.save(to_check([1, 3, 9]))?

Comment: No. You would need to call the to_check([1,4]) method on the model followed by the save method. (I have added this to the original answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think that will code is missing something

```
def to_check=(arr_or_checks)
   @to_check = arr_or_checks
end
```

Then when you want to use it it's something like:

```
mod = Data.find(1)
mod.to_check = [1,4]
mod.save
```

This would save and only check 1 and 4.